# SignalR hosted in azure functions established connection but doesn't trigger SignalRTrigger function

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, signalr

I am working on an Azure Functions project that utilizes SignalR triggers. I've set up my function and configuration, but I keep encountering an error when attempting to run the function locally. The error in the console reads:

[2023-09-06T15:57:30.258Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.actionReceiver'. System.Collections.Concurrent: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key').
[2023-09-06T15:57:30.278Z] Error indexing method 'Functions.actionReceiver'
...
Function 'Functions.actionReceiver' failed indexing and will be disabled.

Here's my function.json for the SignalR triggered function:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "signalRTrigger",
      "name": "req",
      "hubName": "default",
      "event": "clientToServer",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalR",
      "name": "signalRMessages",
      "hubName": "default",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

My local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=signalrfarmstorage;AccountKey=********;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://farmsignalr.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=******;Version=1.0;"
  }
}
```

And my javascript function:

```
module.exports = async function actionReceiver(context, req) {
  console.log('SignalR trigger function processed a request.');
  context.bindings.signalRMessages = [{
    "target": "newMessage",
    "arguments": ["Message from Azure Function"]
  }];
};
```

All the names and settings appear to be aligned, but I can't figure out what's causing the issue. Can anyone help me understand what this error means and how to resolve it? I am unable to start my azure functions without this error and have not been able to find any resources online. I am new to SignalR. Thanks so much to anyone who can provide clarification.

I have been led to believe I am missing an env var needed on startup but I cannot figure out which one.

I have ensured my connection strings in local.settings.json are correct. I restarted VScode in case the env vars were not working. I even tried completely recreating the function and it did not work. I am not sure where this error is coming from. I know the basics of azure functions: I have got timer and http triggers to work very often in the past, I am just unable to get a SignalR one to work.

EDIT:
I have added property "category": "messages" to my function.json. It no longer gives the indexing error but it is still not receiving the signal when I run this code in my frontend on a successfully established connection:

connection.invoke('clientToServer', 'Hello from client!').catch(err => console.error(err));

Comment: are you trying to send message to function from signalR hub or from function to SignalR hub?

Answer (score 0):

> Error indexing method 'Functions.actionReceiver'. System.Collections.Concurrent: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key'). [2023-09-06T15:57:30.278Z] Error indexing method 'Functions.actionReceiver' ... Function 'Functions.actionReceiver' failed indexing and will be disabled.

- Configure that all required settings are properly defined including configuration settings related to SignalR triggers, such as the Azure SignalR connection string, hub name, or other custom settings.

I have tried the same approach. I created a SignalR in azure portal. check the below.

[image]

I am using the similar code as yours and did some changes. The below code is working fine in my Local.

**Function code:**

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
    if (req.query.message) {
        const message = req.query.message;
        context.bindings.signalRMessages = [{
            "target": "newMessage",
            "arguments": [message]
        }];

        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: "Message sent to SignalR."
        };
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please provide a 'message' query parameter."
        };
    }
};
```

**Function.json:**

```json
{
 "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "methods": ["post"],
      "route": "negotiate"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalR",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return",
      "hubName": "default",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "your-azure storage connectionstring",
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString":"your-signalR-connectionstring"
  }
}
```

- My function is executed successfully when I run `func start`.
  check the below:
  [image]

Here I able to send the messages to SignalR successfully.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]